# web3.eth.getBalance returns me the strange values ?

Tags: web3js, web3j

i am trying to get the balance of a wallet, the method is working but the returned result is a json object - `{ c:(2) [484895,26495000000000],e:19, s: 1}`.

In which the value - 484895 corresponds to 48.4895 eth in account 1, value 26495000000000 cooresponds to 26.495 eth in account, my questionis why there is a big difference for the value in the array.  what is the semantics of e(19) and s(1).

the code is below

```
  getBalance (address) {
      return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, result) {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            resolve(result);
            }
        })
      })
    }

   getBalance(account).then((result) => {
         console.log('getBalance',result);
         web3.utils.fromWei(result.c[0], 'ether')
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the **BigNumber representation of the wallet balance** that is output by your script.

Indeed, [BigNumbers](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) need to be transformed through `toString(int)` or `toNumber()` in order to become compatible with javascript `int` or `string`. You can read more about this [here](https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/ethereum_javascript_api.html#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-javascript) and [here](https://ethereumbuilders.gitbooks.io/guide/content/en/ethereum_javascript_api.html#web3ethgetbalance).

To understand the object output, I found on BigNumbers's git that:

> The value of a BigNumber is stored in a decimal floating point format in terms of a coefficient, exponent and sign.

So `x = new BigNumber(-123.456); console.log(x);` would output : `{ c:(2) [123,456], e:2, s: -1}`, with

- c : coefficients / significand
- e : exponent
- s : sign

---

In your case the exponent equals 19 because the smallest unit of ether is the **WEI = 10-18 eth**.

To find the value, this is how you can process:

- **c(1) concatenated to c(2)** form the **significant digits**, called C
- **19** is the **exponent** of your number in its [modified normalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand), regarding the base 10, meaning in the shape x.y*10^n , with x in the **range 1.0 to 10**
- **-1** is the **sign**

this means **`48.489526... = 4.8489526... * 10 ^ 19 * -1`**

You should then divide the value obtained through `BigNumber.toNumber()` by 10^18 to get a correct ETH amount to show to the user.