# How to interpreter result of web3.eth.getBalance

Tags: web3js, truffle

I got following result from getBalance check:
truffle(default)> web3.eth.getBalance('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

Can anyone explain what does it means and where the value of ether: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }?

Comment: A similar question has been answered here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41352/web3-eth-getbalance-returns-me-the-strange-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the BigNumber into a string to have a readable value

```
web3.eth.getBalance('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').toString()
```

the output value would be in wei.

You can use `web3.fromWei(number, unit)` to convert it in another unit (eg. ether). [ref](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei)